# Button background color configuration is not applied in some cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a certain GUI which includes a button. This button is disabled until some condition is met. When the user clicks this button, I call a function `onBurnClick` which does some actions and when it finishes it verifies something in the background. If the verification is positive I color `button2` background in green and if it is negative I color this button's background in red.

This function is also bound to the `<Return>` key. But for some reason only when I click the button the background coloring, at the end of the process, is visible. Pressing the `<Return>` key does all the rest except for the button background coloring.

By the way, I had to set the focus on `button2` in order to make the binding successful. I set the focus at the same conditions that I make `button2` active.

```
class Second_Screen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.main_frame, text="Burn",
                            command=lambda: self.onBurnClick(),
                            font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button2.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, pady=(20,0))

        self.button2.bind("<Return>", self.onBurnClick)

   def onBurnClick(self, event=None):           
        if some_conditions:
            self.button2.config(bg='springgreen2')
            self.after(3000, self.return2default)
        else:
            self.button2.config(bg='red2')

   def return2default(self):
       self.button2.config(bg='SystemButtonFace')
```

What do I need to do in order to have the same background coloring on the `<Return>` key press event too ?

Comment: I found out that the background color changes upon a mouse hovering action. In order to get the background color change I need to move the mouse cursor over the button right after I clicked the '<Return>' key. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: To make it more precise, the background color changes upon button leave. Meaning, if I point the button during the <Return> key press or SPACEBAR key press and leave it right after this key press the background color change will occur

Comment: Maybe there is a way to generate a <Leave> event that relates to the button. Or, trigger in other way this kind of event ? Is this a limitation of the Button.config function ?

Comment: By isolating the button background color change actions in order to understand this issue better I revealed that the button cannot show interim background color configurations even if I isolate these changes in separate methods and delay the transition from one state to the other. Is there a way to make these interim changes to be seen (step by step) ?